# AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.vision' has no attribute 'Image'

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the `web_detection` function of `Google Vision`. I use the `Image` function to provide the image link to web detection. This was working until recently. But suddenly getting that error that `Image() is not an attribute of vision`. I'm not able to find any new methods in the documentation as well.

```
>>> client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
>>> image = vision.Image()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.vision' has no attribute 'Image'
```

Comment: I think it is `image = client.Image()` on second line.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, the `Image` class is no longer available in the `google.cloud.vision` module
 so, you can use the `types` module to create an image object that can be used with the `web_detection` function.

Maybe it's better to import the `vision_v1p3beta1` module instead of the `vision` module, because the `web_detection` function is only available in the beta version of the Cloud Vision API.

let me give you an example via `web_detection` function with an image url, I will using the `types` module to create an `Image` object from an image url,
 I then pass this object to the `web_detection` function to perform web detection on the image.

```
from google.cloud import vision_v1p3beta1 as vision
from google.cloud.vision_v1p3beta1 import types

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
image = types.Image()
image.source.image_uri = 'https://test.com/pic.jpg'

response = client.web_detection(image=image)
web_entities = response.web_detection.web_entities

for entity in web_entities:
    print(entity.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked documentation and `ImageAnnotatorClient` is a class that it is not in `google.cloud.vision` package. Therefore, it is not possible that you import `ImageAnnotatorClient` from `google.cloud.vision` package with the latest version of `google-cloud-vision`.

I think that `ImageAnnotatorClient` that you imported is from `google.cloud.vision_v1` package.

You need to write this:

```
from google.cloud import vision

image = vision.Image()
```